# Spring e Jasper - Browser não entende streaming para download

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, java-ee-7

Tenho uma aplicação que usa [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) versão 6.2.0 com [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) versão 3.2.14, [java-ee-7](/questions/tagged/java-ee-7), [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) 8 e no front-end utilizamos [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs). As requisições [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) são feitas via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

O Spring entende perfeitamente o objeto [json](/questions/tagged/json) que vem na URL e o relatório parece estar sendo gerado da maneira correta também, pois testamos passando um JSON mal-formatado e tomamos naturalmente uma exceção.

O problema é que ao retornar para o browser, a requisição não é interpretada de maneira alguma como para se fazer o download do arquivo e cospe apenas o conteúdo do arquivo, inclusive sem o cabeçalho que o jasper-reports gera para arquivos PDF.

Quando escrevo o conteúdo do vetor de bytes no [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) do HttpServletResponse o cabeçalho do arquivo sai como posso ver no response que o Chrome mostra no console. Essa parte do código está visível no código abaixo do método, porém comentada.

**Método que recebe a requisição:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = RequisicaoPoRestService.ROOT_MAPPING_CIA_REQUISICOES_PO + "/pdfdetalhepedido", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Secured({ "ROLE_CONSULTARPO" })
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> gerarPDFDetalhePedido(final HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable(RequisicaoPoRestService.ID_CIA) final Long idCia,
        @RequestParam("detelhePedidoJson") final String detelhePedidoJson) {
    // Parametrizar via properties.
    final String caminhoTemplate = "C:\\Projetos\\wasp\\wasp-api\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\pdftemplates\\Blank_A4.jasper";
    final byte[] relatorio = PdfUtils.gerarPDFViaJSON(caminhoTemplate, detelhePedidoJson, null);

    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store");
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    headers.setPragma("no-cache");
    headers.setDate(0);
    headers.setContentLength(relatorio.length);
    headers.setExpires(0);
    headers.setLastModified(0);
    headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DetalhePedido.pdf");

    // response.reset();
    // response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" +
    // filename);
    // response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    // response.setContentLength(relatorio.length);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(relatorio, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Método que gera o relatório**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static byte[] gerarPDFViaJSON(final String caminhoDoTemplateDeNFe, final String json, final String logo) {
    try (final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes())) {

        // Fonte de Dados.
        final JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(stream);

        // Parâmetros
        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        // params.put("Logo", logo);

        // Gerando o relatório
        final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminhoDoTemplateDeNFe, params, ds);

        // Exportando em pdf.
        final byte[] relatorio = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
        return Arrays.copyOf(relatorio, relatorio.length);
    } catch (final JRException | IOException e) {
        PdfUtils.LOGGER.error(e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Alguma sugestão do motivo da requisição não estar sendo interpretada para ser feito o download do arquivo, mesmo eu limpando cache, setando que no header da mesma que é um arquivo para download, seu tamanho e etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri depois de muita pesquisa, tentativa e erro que o problema não estava no código, mas sim no meu esquecimento que requisições [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) retornam apenas texto, ou seja, impossível retornar um array de bytes.

Feita a chamada com um get "comum" ao invés de usar chamadas [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) que são sempre via Ajax tudo passou a funcionar.